# Raspberry pi - Black screen after chmod etc permissions

Tags: raspberry-pi4

I was changing permissions of some letsencrypt info on my raspberry pi to be very stringent. I later realized that I should make it more secure, and chmodded that folder, but also the /etc folder to 700 permissions.

I was dumb in doing this, and thought things would still be ok. Afterwards, I lost control and restarted. Ever since, I cannot get into my raspberry pi fully. It has a black screen with only a cursor. I have attempted to ssh into it, and have the ability to. However, I can only sign in with the username pi, so I can't chmod my /etc folder.

I also never set the password to root, so I don't know how to get in. It asks for a password if I try to ssh in as root, and putting in nothing doesn't work.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, username pi has ability to run as root using sudo, e.g. one of these may work for you:

```
sudo chmod 744 /etc
```

or

```
sudo su
chmod 744 /etc
exit (which takes you back to username pi)
```